# Issue on Java LinkedHashSet contains method

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I am having this problem with a LinkedHashSet and its contains method.
Let me summarize it to you.

I have this class C1 with 4 String attributes, its respective getters and setters as well as equals(), and hashCode() methods as given by default by eclipse.

Then I have another class C2 that has 1 attribute of type LinkedHashSet with the getSet() method for accessing it.

When I create 1 instance of a C1 class (say object c1) and add it to an instance c2 of class C2, everything is fine... I do:

```
C1 c1 = new C1("a", "b", "c", "d");
C2 c2 = new C2();
c2.getSet().add(c1);
```

Now if I set a different value to the first attribute of c1, with the appropriate set method, and then I try to check if c2.getSet() contains element c1... but it always returns false. 
But the hashcode of the object changed and the one within the set is the same, and apparently, the equals test in the contains method is failing...

Does anyone understand what is happening here?
What can be wrong? Equals and HashCode()?

Thanks in advance,
cheers

Comment: If the hashCode changed, the HashSet will never find it.  Read the warnings in the documentation.

Comment: Can you include your Equals and HashCode implementations...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing hashCode of object stored in hash-based collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174233/changing-hashcode-of-object-stored-in-hash-based-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an object to a hash set(or hash map or any collection that uses hashing to lookup objects), the collection class puts the object into a 'bucket' based on the hashcode computed for the object. After this, you change an attribute of the object, because of which the hashcode of the object will be different the next time it is calculated. However, the object is in the location/bucket corresponding to the old hashcode. So when you try to find the object with the changed attributes and hashcode, the set looks in the wrong bucket and finds it empty.
There is nothing wrong with either the hash code or equals method. The mistake you are making here is this: Never change the fields of an object which are used in hashmap calculation once the object is put into a hash set or hash map. As a best practice, make those attributes of C1 as final if you know that you are going to put it into a hash set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually understand how HashMap works, but got a bit confused when it came to a Set. But since HashSet uses HashMap inside and uses the set element as key, it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashSet collection will not follow your internal modifications.
By changing c1 contents, I think you changed the hashCode of the object.
So, LinkedHashSet cannot retrieves it when you call contains.

Comment: You can check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more understanding.