# HashSet.remove() fails to behave according to spec?

Tags: java, set

According to JDK docs for HashSet, remove() :

> removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if
>   this set contains such an element.

Well, here is a tiny bit of code that proves otherwise.  The Set points definitely contains my point, as evidenced by equals(), and yet, remove() mysteriously fails to remove it.  The trouble seems to be somehow due to the change of value of point.x (line 4 of main()).  Omitting this makes everything behave as expected.

Note that the following behaves normally if points is an ArrayList rather than a HashSet.

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class RemoveTest2 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Collection<Point2D.Double> points = new HashSet<Point2D.Double>();
        final Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double();
        points.add(point);
        point.x++;

        // make sure that points definitely contains the point we are trying to remove...
        for (final Point2D.Double p : points) {
            if (point.equals(p)) {
                System.out.println("points definitely contains " + point);
                System.out.println(point.hashCode() + " == " + p.hashCode());
            }
        }

        if (!points.remove(point)) {
            System.out.println("and yet... failed to remove " + point);
        }
        System.out.println("points cointains " + points.size());
    }

}
```

The spec seems painfully clear... Please, somebody explain to me what I am missing here.

Comment: it's final - that's why. You can evaluate points.add(point) and it will be 0

Comment: Can you post ``Point2D.Double``?

Comment: yes...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html

Comment: I'm sorry, what is final?  And why does being final change the behavior of anything?  The return value of add() is actually boolean, and in my example, it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you change the hashcode of an object after using it, so the Hashset cannot get the existing object using the new hashcode (as it is stored using old hashcode).

When changing such fields, you need to first remove this object before changing it, than store it again.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174485/1651233)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Just wow.
Am I alone in thinking that this sort of behavior explicitly violates the very simple contract set forth in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29 ... since JDK 1.2?

Comment: I agree, it is shocking. That's one reason for using immutable objects only.

Comment: It's not as shocking if you remember that a basic feature of polymorphism is that contracts are inherited, meaning the entire HashSet class must adhere to the contract of the Set class, which [goes out of its way to point out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) that “Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.”